# How to parse string statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I want to parse this statement in javascript

```
["TWA"]["STEL"]
```

and get TWA, STEL value. I guess this is a json and use JSON.parse() method but doesn't work.

Comment: No it is not JSON. A regex would work.  If you want to use JSON.parse you need `JSON.parse('["TWA"]["STEL"]'.replace('][',','))`

Comment: This is not valid JSON and cannot be parsed as such. You could use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as a quick way of lexing this. Or, you could split on "[" (or "]") and remove the unwanted characters from the parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a JSON, but you can easily parse it with the pattern matcher:

https://jsfiddle.net/60dshj3x/

```js
let text = '["TWA"]["STEL"]'
let results = text.match(/\["(.*)"\]\["(.*)"]/)

// note that results[0] is always the entire string!
let first = results[1]
let second = results[2]

console.log("First: " + first + "\nSecond: " + second);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a **string** then a simple **regex** will do the trick.

```js
const regex = /\["(\w+)"\]/gm;
const str = `["TWA"]["STEL"]`;
let m;
let words = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
   if(groupIndex===1)words.push(match)
  });
}

console.log(words.join(','))
```

Comment: Or shorter: `JSON.parse('["TWA"]["STEL"]'.replace('][',','))`

Comment: For this `["TWA."]["STEL"]` that approach doesn't work.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes sir, totally agreed with you :) May I edit my answer?

Comment: @Ele agree. but OP posted string like `["TWA"]["STEL"]` that's why I used that

Comment: Just leave my comment. No need to add it to your answer